# Remove class from other siblings

Tags: jquery, css, list, selectors-api

I have a structure like

```
<ul>
  <li class="open active">
    <a></a>
    <ul class="submenu nav-show" style="display:block"></ul>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a></a>
    <ul></ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

when user click on second `li` then from first `li's ul` which containing `nav-show` will be `nav-hide` and style will be `display:hide`

Till now I have tried

```
var open = document.querySelectorAll(".open");
var a=$(open).closest("li").addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
$(a).siblings().closest("ul").removeClass('nav-hide').addClass('nav-show');
```

But its not working
also tried

```
var open = document.querySelectorAll(".open");
$(open).closest("li").addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
$(open).not(":has(.active)").collapse('hide');
```

but not giving proper output 
plz help me

Comment: Please share you onclick handler so we can see what you are actually trying to do

Comment: can you provide a fiddle???

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I exactly want sidemenu of http://responsiweb.com/themes/preview/ace/1.3.3/ ..click on subchild other will be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$($p).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').end()
.parent().children().filter(function(){return $(this).find('.nav-show ').length>0}).addClass('.nav-hide').hide();
```

Or

```
$($p).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').end()
.siblings().filter(function(){return $(this).find('.nav-show ').length>0}).addClass('.nav-hide').hide();
```

try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mjvakili/ougyu0f2/1/)

Comment: thnx its partially working it hides first lis ul but also hide second lis ul

Comment: @BDhara please retest.

Comment: it hides parent ul while i want only li hide

Comment: @BDhara please retest.

Comment: <ul class="nav nav-list">
<li  class="open">
<ul class="submenu nav-show" id="list" style="display: block;">
<li>
 <a  class="dropdown-toggle clickme" href="#" >AiringCupboard</a>
 <ul class="submenu">
  <li>
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Audios</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>
 <a  class="dropdown-toggle clickme" href="#" >Kitchen</a>
 <ul class="submenu">
  <li>
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Audios</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: plz see this structure ..I have this kinda ul and li ur code is removing whole parent ul

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75354/discussion-between-mj-vakili-and-bdhara).

Comment: second query is working but it add nav-hide into uls li where I want to add that class into uls lis ul

Comment: @BDhara test code.
$('.nav-list li a').off() 
$('.nav-list li a').click(function () { 
$(this).next().show().addClass('nav-show'); 
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').find('.nav-show').addClass('nav-hide').hide(); 
});

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings("li.active").find("ul.nav-show:eq(1)").removeClass("nav-show").addClass("nav-hide");
        $(this).siblings("li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).find("ul").removeClass("nav-hide").addClass("nav-show");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sh9fdLn9/2/)

Comment: Oh yea!! It is but you cannot visualize it!! You might need to add some sub-menus to show it perfectly!! or else I just noted it in DOM!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao updated the fiddle .. how about that.. ?

Comment: @BDhara you can see the fiddle now maybe this time you get the picture??

Comment: <ul class="nav nav-list">
<li  class="open">
<ul class="submenu nav-show" id="list" style="display: block;">
<li>
 <a  class="dropdown-toggle clickme" href="#" >AiringCupboard</a>
 <ul class="submenu nav-show">
  <li>
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Audios</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>
 <a  class="dropdown-toggle clickme" href="#" >Kitchen</a>
 <ul class="submenu">
  <li>
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Audios</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: I have nav-show two times..i want second nav-show hides

Comment: where i have to add :eq? and what does it do?

Comment: @BDhara in the first line of .click function ... and it selects the second ul in side the li tag 1 is the index passes to this selector ..index starts with 0..

Comment: I tried..    $(open).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').end().siblings().filter(function () { return $(this).find('.nav-show').eq(1).length > 0 }).addClass('nav-hide').hide(); but it close after two li open

Answer (score 1):

the `closest` function will get the closest parent of the element. In your case `open` will be the same element as the element you want `.active` on.

Try changing `var a=$(open).closest("li")` to `var a=$(open)` and see if that helps

Comment: still same as previous..no effects

Answer (score 1):

try this coding

```
$("li > a").click(function() {
        var $div1 = $(this).next();
        $(".submenu").not($div1).hide();
        $div1.show();
        var $div2=$(this).parent();
        $("li").not($div2).removeClass('active');
        $div2.addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: It hides whole parent ul not li

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$('.open').addClass('active').find('ul').removeClass('nav-hide').addClass('nav-show').end().siblings('.active').removeClass('active').find('ul').addClass('nav-hide').removeClass('nav-show');
```

---

Same can be written as

```
var $li = $('.open').addClass('active');
$li.find('ul').removeClass('nav-hide').addClass('nav-show');
$li.siblings('.active').removeClass('active').find('ul').addClass('nav-hide').removeClass('nav-show');
```